# Qt3Dでカスタムメッシュで線を表示したいが，エラーログが出て描画されない

Tags: c++, qt

## やりたいこと

Qt3D(Qt6.4.2)で，QGeometryやQGeometryRendererを継承したLineMeshを作成し，表示したいです．

## 問題

実行時に以下のようなエラーがアプリケーション出力に表示されラインは描画されません．

```
clientcore\windows\dwm\dwmapi\attribute.cpp(157)\dwmapi.dll!00007FFBBAA437B1: (caller: 00007FFB4F8D610B) LogHr(1) tid(3084) 80070006 ハンドルが無効です。
clientcore\windows\dwm\dwmapi\attribute.cpp(178)\dwmapi.dll!00007FFBBAA43657: (caller: 00007FFB4F8D612D) ReturnHr(1) tid(3084) 80070057 パラメーターが間違っています。
```

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout: The provided input signature expects to read an element with SemanticName/Index: 'TEXCOORD'/1, but the declaration doesn't provide a matching name. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #163: CREATEINPUTLAYOUT_MISSINGELEMENT]
```

```
Exception at 0x7ffbbd32cd29, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in d3d11!D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent
Failed to create input layout: Error 0x80070057: ?p?????[?^?[??????????????B
Qt3D.Renderer.RHI.Backend: Failed to build graphics pipeline: Creation Failed
```

1つ目と3つ目の出力はデバックモードで表示されます．
2つ目の出力はリリースモードでも表示されます．
また，アプリケーションを終了する(ウィンドウを閉じる)とcrashします．

## コード

```cpp
LineGeometry::LineGeometry(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DCore::QGeometry(parent)
    , _origin(QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
    , _direction(QVector3D(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f))
    , positionAttribute(new Qt3DCore::QAttribute(this))
    , indexAttribute(new Qt3DCore::QAttribute(this))
    , positionBuffer(new Qt3DCore::QBuffer(this))
    , indexBuffer(new Qt3DCore::QBuffer(this))
{
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DCore::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DCore::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DCore::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(positionBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setVertexSize(3); //(x,y,z)
    positionAttribute->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float)); //(x,y,z) * float
    positionAttribute->setCount(2); //{start,end}

    positionArray.resize(3 * 2 * sizeof(float)); //(x,y,z) * {start,end} * float

    indexAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DCore::QAttribute::UnsignedShort);
    indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DCore::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
    indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexBuffer);
    indexAttribute->setCount(2); //{start,end}

    QByteArray indexArray;
    indexArray.resize(2 * sizeof(unsigned short)); //(x,y,z) * {start,end} * unsigned short
    unsigned short *i = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(indexArray.data());
    *i++ = 0;
    *i++ = 1;
    indexBuffer->setData(indexArray);

    addAttribute(positionAttribute);
    addAttribute(indexAttribute);

    updatePositionData();
}

void LineGeometry::updatePositionData()
{
    const QVector3D end = _origin + _direction;

    float *p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(positionArray.data());

    *p++ = _origin.x();
    *p++ = _origin.y();
    *p++ = _origin.z();

    *p++ = end.x();
    *p++ = end.y();
    *p++ = end.z();

    positionBuffer->setData(positionArray);
}

LineGeometryView::LineGeometryView(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DCore::QGeometryView(parent)
{
    LineGeometry *geometry = new LineGeometry(this);

    connect(geometry, &LineGeometry::originChanged, this, &LineGeometryView::originChanged);
    connect(geometry, &LineGeometry::directionChanged, this, &LineGeometryView::directionChanged);

    setGeometry(geometry);

    setPrimitiveType(Qt3DCore::QGeometryView::PrimitiveType::Lines);
}

LineMesh::LineMesh(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(parent)
{
    LineGeometryView *geometry = new LineGeometryView(this);

    connect(geometry, &LineGeometryView::originChanged, this, &LineMesh::originChanged);
    connect(geometry, &LineGeometryView::directionChanged, this, &LineMesh::directionChanged);

    setView(geometry);

    setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Lines);
}
```

````cpp
SceneWindow::SceneWindow()
    : Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow()
{
    /* ``` 省略 ``` */

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lineEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(lineEntity);
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lineTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lineEntity);
    LineMesh *lineMesh = new LineMesh(lineEntity);
    lineEntity->setParent(rootEntity);
    lineEntity->addComponent(lineMaterial);
    lineEntity->addComponent(lineTransform);
    lineEntity->addComponent(lineMesh);

    /* ``` 省略 ``` */
}
````

## その他

コードはqtのリポジトリにあるextrasを見ながら参考に書きました．
もちろん，このLineをシーンに追加しなければこのようなエラーは起こりませんでした．

## 環境

Windows Qt6.4.2 MSVC2019 64bit